# React Server Side rendering is rerendered in frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, serverside-javascript

in this isomorphic example https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example he shows Server Side Rendering by disabling Javascript. But if javascript IS enabled in frontend, is it rendered again?

I did a small test by putting a console.log in the render function and it logs in the NodeJS console but also in the browser's console.

Is react intelligent enough to not rerender if the HTML comes from the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will render again in the sense that all of the React Component `render` functions will run again. It will not necessarily change the DOM at all however because React's diffing algorithm will not do anything if the correct DOM nodes are already in the page.

Comment: But it's making call to all the Ajax again . Which is bad , how can I stop re-rendering , atleast in production

Comment: I'm guessing serverside you aren't making "ajax" calls, but instead passing initial state into your react components.  If you are relying on the components to make the requests, those probably won't fire on the server and the initial render will do so without data, then make the ajax requests.  Ultimately, you can make the ajax request conditional on whether or not the property or state has a value.